# How to Query Multiple Associated Tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two associated table in my application and I cannot figure it how to join them together in rails, below is my Model:

```
class Lead < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :employee_leads
    has_many :employees, :through => :employee_leads
end

class EmployeeLead < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :employee
    belongs_to :lead
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :employee_leads
    has_many :leads, :through => employee_leads
    has_many :emp_stores
    has_many :stores, :through => emp_stores
end

class EmpStore < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :store
    belongs_to :employee
end

class Store < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :emp_stores
    has_many :employees, :through => :emp_stores
end
```

My application required me to find out which store each lead belongs to.  I know how to join the lead to the employee, which is:

```
Lead.joins(employee_leads: :employee)
```

and I also know how to join the employee to the store

```
Employee.joins(emp_stores: :store)
```

Those are working for me without issue.  When I try to get the lead join to store, I used:

```
Lead.joins(employee_leads: :employee { emp_stores: :store })
```

This gave me a syntax error, I refer to the [link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) of Active Record regarding Joining Nested Associations (Multiple Level) and I still can't figure it out.  I'm very new to this, please someone take some time to explain and help me out.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Lead.joins(employee_leeds: [employee: [amp_stores: :store] ])
```

I believe these variants should also work:

```
Lead.joins(employee_leeds: [{employee: [{amp_stores: :store}] }])
Lead.joins(employee_leeds: {employee: {amp_stores: :store} })
```

Although, depending on how you're using this you might want to consider using `includes` rather than `joins`. Joins are lazy-loaded whereas includes are eager-loaded.

As an explanation to why your syntax was wrong ... `:something` is a symbol. And in the old (pre ruby 1.9) world, hash key/value pairs were written like so: `:key => :value`. However, from Ruby 1.9 the newer syntax of `key: :value` was provided.

In your attempt to get this working you had a key/value pair followed (without a separator) by another hash. In order to fix it, you need to provide just one value to the first key:

```
# Old syntax
:employee_leads => [ :employee => [ :emp_stores => :store ] ]
```

Which when you consider the new syntax for hashes, hopefully makes this more logical to understand:

```
# New syntax
employee_leads: [ employee: [ emp_stores: :store ] ]
```

Comment: Thank you, the new syntax one worked fine with the curly brackets.